# Improve Data structure with double properties

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have data structure where most of properties are same thing from another table. I have Component1, Code1, Description1 and Argument1, and I have same thing but from different table(Component2, Code2, Description2 and Argument2). This properties can be same and does not have to be. 
 In first table is new imported data, and in second table is old data. Now I need to compare this data and take one or another base on some logic. One of important reasons why I need this data structure is because I need to check if Code1 is equals to Code2 (same for argument, component and description).

```
 public class ImportData
    {
        private int id { get; set; }

        private int Component1 { get; set; }
        private int Component2 { get; set; }

        private string Code1 { get; set; }
        private string Code2 { get; set; }

        private string Description1 { get; set; }
        private string Description2 { get; set; }

        private string Argument1 { get; set; }
        private string Argument2 { get; set; }

        private bool isValid { get; set; }

    }
```

I have feeling that there must be better way to do this. I don't like to have so many "same" properties 2 times. I plan to have List, I don't have just one object but very long list of this objects. Any idea?
Thanks for help.

Comment: No, type is same. But value can be, but does not have to same. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would create a new class that represents a pair of objects:

```
public class Pair<T>
{
    public T Item1 { get; set; }
    public T Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

(or if you want it immutable, remove the `set` and add a constructor that gets both items as parameters)

Then you can define `ImportData` as follows:

```
public class ImportData
{
    private int id { get; set; }

    private Pair<int> Component { get; set; }
    private Pair<string> Code { get; set; }
    private Pair<string> Description { get; set; }
    private Pair<string> Argument { get; set; }

    private bool isValid { get; set; }
}
```

This alone makes your code more readable, which is a good thing. But then you can add extra utility members to the `Pair` class such as `ItemsAreEqual`, that will help you to prevent code duplication.

**Update:** as an alternative to creating the `Pair` class, take a look at the already existing [Tuple class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make things shorter that doesn't necessarily can, or need to be, shorter. Your argument that you can have separate values for all fields, and you all need to compare them, actually tells all these fields need to be there.

To make this a little more optimized, you could add a second class `Data`, which you will reference inside your class:

```
public class Data
{
    private int Component { get; set; }
    private string Code { get; set; }
    private string Description { get; set; }
    private string Argument { get; set; }
}
```

And the original class:

```
public class ImportData
{
    private int id { get; set; }

    private Data Left { get; set; }
    private Data Right { get; set; }

    private bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

One benefit is that you can derive `Equals` in your `Data` class, so you can easily compare both of them to check their equality.

Answer (score 1):

You can create class with properties just one time and implement the [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.

```
public class Data : IComparable
{
    public int Component { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Argument { get; set; } 

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        var other = obj as Data;
        if(other == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not Data");
        }
        else
        {
            //compare current instance to other here...
        }
    }
}
```